# How to fix: i18n always translate to default locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-i18n

I'm trying out the internationalization of a Rails app with i18n. I did some small tests with 2 languages: english and french.

The problem I have is that i18n always translate to the default locale. So if it's english, everything will be in english, and the same with french.

Here is what I tried:

**config/initializers/locales.rb**

```
# Permitted locales available for the application
I18n.available_locales = [:en, :fr]
```

**app/controllers/application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

    def default_url_options
        { locale: I18n.locale }
    end

end
```

**config/application.rb**

```
module LanguageApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    ...
    config.i18n.load_path += Dir["#{Rails.root.to_s}/config/locales/**/*.{rb,yml}"]
    config.i18n.default_locale = :en
    # I change the default locale here to :fr or :en
  end
end
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
root to: "home#index"

get '/:locale/about' => 'about#index'
get '/:locale' => 'home#index'
```

I organized my yml files like this:

**config/locales/views/about/en.yml**

```
en:
  about: "This page is about us."
```

**config/locales/views/about/fr.yml**

```
fr:
  about: "Cette page est à propos de nous."
```

**config/locales/views/home/en.yml**

```
en:
  welcome: "Hello world"
```

**config/locales/views/home/fr.yml**

```
fr:
  welcome: "Bonjour le monde"
```

And finally my views:

**app/views/about/index.html.erb**

```
About us page. <%= t(:about) %>
```

**app/views/home/index.html.erb**

```
This is the homepage. <%= t(:welcome) %>
```

I think the problem may come from the way I organized my yml files but I don't understand why i18n only translate to the default locale and 'ignore' the other language.

EDIT:

To try this out in the browser with the rails server running, I tried to visit these URL:

```
localhost:3000
localhost:3000/en
localhost:3000/fr
```

These 3 URL give me the same content, so the :fr locale doesn't actually work (it returns the same translation as :en)

Same for

```
localhost:3000/en/about
localhost:3000/fr/about
```

I also tried it in the rails console:

```
> I18n.t(:welcome, :en)
"Hello world"
> I18n.t(:welcome, :fr)
"Hello world"
```

Comment: I cannot see that you are setting/changing I18n.locale when a new locale comes from params

Comment: I forgot to mention how I changed it indeed. I'm editing my question right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First set the locale for the request:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    around_action :switch_locale
 
    def switch_locale(&action)
        I18n.with_locale(params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale, &action)
    end

    def default_url_options
        { locale: I18n.locale }
    end
end
```

Don't use `I18n.locale=` as many older answers / tutorials do.

> I18n.locale can leak into subsequent requests served by the same
> thread/process if it is not consistently set in every controller. For
> example executing I18n.locale = :es in one POST requests will have
> effects for all later requests to controllers that don't set the
> locale, but only in that particular thread/process. For that reason,
> instead of I18n.locale = you can use I18n.with_locale which does not
> have this leak issue.
>
> - [Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#configure-the-i18n-module)

If you want to create translations for specific views you should nest the keys instead of just using flat hashes:

```
en:
  home:
    welcome: "Hello World"

fr:
  home:
    welcome: "Bonjour le monde"
```

And then use an implicit lookup in the view:

```
<h1><%= t('.welcome') %></h1>
```

This resolves the key to `home.welcome`.

Comment: Thanks, it works now. What I was missing is the switch_locale method, after that everything is fine. Thanks!